# Python BeautifulSoup: wildcard attribute/id search

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this:

```
dates = soup.findAll("div", {"id" : "date"})
```

However, I need id to be a wildcard search since the `id` can be `date_1`, `date_2` etc.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can provide a callable as a filter:

```
dates = soup.findAll("div", {"id" : lambda L: L and L.startswith('date')})
```

Or as @DSM points out

```
dates = soup.findAll("div", {"id" : re.compile('date.*')})
```

as BeautifulSoup will recognise a RegExp object and call its `.match()` method.

Comment: That gives me an error "'NoneType' object has no attribute startswith "

Comment: @user984003 okies - not sure what'd cause that - updated post

Comment: You could also pass a regex, like `re.compile('date*')`.

Comment: @DSM keep forgetting about that one - added to post - thank you

Comment: The regexp worked, although not the lambda. Thanks. I'll leave it a bit and see if anyone knows why, else I'll mark it as correct for the regexp.

Comment: `'NoneType' object has no attribute startswith` can happen because when there is no `id` specified in the source HTML, `None` will be passed as the filter argument. `L and` protects against this. Is it possible you left this off and were using just `lambda L: L.startswith('date')`? Because that would explain your error.

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you! About the none type, I often forget that find_all returns a list and then try to apply a new find_all on it and it returns a NoneType error. So I just add [n] at the end of every find_all like this: soup.findAll("div", {"id" : lambda L: L and L.startswith('date')})[0].find_all(*)

Comment: Why does it not work to do only "lambda L: L.startswith("something")", instead of "lambda L: L and L.startswith("")"?