# Understanding lambda function in python

Tags: python, lambda, beautifulsoup

I was looking at this post:

[Python BeautifulSoup: wildcard attribute/id search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257717/python-beautifulsoup-wildcard-attribute-id-search)

in which the answer gives a solution:

`dates = soup.findAll("div", {"id" : lambda L: L and L.startswith('date')})`

I thought I understood the lambda function in python. However, when I look at this 
`lambda L: L and L.startswith('date')`, I understand that it ultimately returns an id which has a value that contains 'date'. But why is it written as `L and L.startswith('date')` ? This looks the lambda function is returning a string and a boolean statement.

Can someone explain the logic behind this please ?

Comment: Think of it as a filter, you're finding all instances of "div" in the soup that have an attribute "id" that starts with the string "date".  The lambda in this case is a predicate function.  The "L and L.startswith('date')" is necessary in case L is None, in which case it would throw an exception.

Comment: @Marcin I see what you mean now and I was wrong. Removed my comments, sorry I caused confusion

Comment: @Chinegro As you see, you were being misled previously.

Comment: @TimCastelijns No need to apologise. I have also removed my comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`and` does not actually return a boolean value, that is it doesn't always return True or False.

What it does is it checks the first value for truthiness. A few things are falsy, like `None`, or `0`, or `False`, or `[]`. Other things are truthy.

If the first value is falsy, it is returned. If it's truthy, the second value is returned. If you only consider the truthiness value of the result, then that is the short-circuit implementation of the `and` logical operator.

The reason why it's used in `lambda L: L and L.startswith('date')` is to make sure this function doesn't throw an exception in case `L` is `None`. If it is, the lambda immediately returns `None` because it is falsy. Without the check, the startswith() call would throw an exception as None doesn't have that method.

Try out the following on the Python prompt:

```
l = lambda L: L and L.startswith('date')

l(None)
l('')
l('does not start with date')
l('date this one does')
l(0)
l(1)
```

Comment: Good answer. Depressing that it needs three people to come along before one of them actually understands a core language feature like boolean operators.

Answer (score 1):

As the your linked post stated, the `lambda` acts as a filter. Its not going to find all `div`s with the ID of the return value of the `lambda`; that wouldn't be useful because IDs need to be unique.

Instead, `soup.findall` is only going to find the `div`s whose ID is validated by the `lambda`, that is any `div` whose ID is not empty and starts with the string `'date'`.

Comment: -1 Lambda does not act as a filter. It's a callable expression.

Comment: @Marcin I understand that. However, the `lambda` function can be used to filter information.