# Finding all posts of a unique identifer using BeautifulSoup and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanted to do something very simple, basically scraping the forum titles of a forum. The problem I ran into is that these forum thread names are identified by a unique "id" tag which is unique.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
threads = requests.get('url', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(threads1) 
results = soup.findAll("a", href=True, id=True)
```

This leaves me with a large non-parsed chunk of information. Alot.
However this is the part I truly want to extract:

```
<a href="/t2518206" id="thread_title_2518206">
title of thread - bla bla bla</a>
```

The problem as you can see is that every single thread_title_000000
has a unique number after it. So I can't isolate it using class or tag statements?
I was thinking I could make a loop with a number range that would go through all the ids' with a unique number, however I don't know how.
It feels ineffective of continuously minimizing the html code chunk if my objective extraction is identified by a unique id.

Comment: check out this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257717/python-beautifulsoup-wildcard-attribute-id-search).. exact same problem