# Scraping .aspx page with python (HKEX)

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap the following website: http://www.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/advancedsearch/search_active_main_c.aspx

I'm using python2.7, Here is my code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,zh;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.5',}

class MyOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36'

myopener = MyOpener()
url = 'http://www.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/advancedsearch/search_active_main_c.aspx'

f = myopener.open(url)
soup_dummy = BeautifulSoup(f,"html5lib")

viewstate = soup_dummy.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
viewstategen = soup_dummy.select("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")[0]['value']

soup_dummy.find(id="aspnetForm")


formData = (
    ('__VIEWSTATE', viewstate),
    ('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR', viewstategen),
    ('ctl00$txt_stock_code', '00005')
)

encodedFields = urllib.urlencode(formData)
# second HTTP request with form data
f = myopener.open(url, encodedFields)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f,"html5lib")
date = soup.find("span", id="lbDateTime")
print(date)
```

Nothing can be collected.
It shows "none" when I run this code.
If I change print(date) to print(date.text) 
Error occur: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: whats the problem ?

Comment: nothing can collect. It shows "none"
if I change print(date) to print(date.text)
Error occur:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little vague, but here's my attempt:

Running your code gives me the following response: `The page requested may have been relocated, renamed or removed from the Hong Kong Exchanges and Clearing Limited, or HKEX, website.`

Additionally, I don't see any span ids equal to `lbDateTime`. I do however see span ids that end with `lbDateTime`. If you are not receiving such an error, you might try this instead: `dates = soup.findAll("span", {"id": lambda L: L and L.endswith('lbDateTime')})`

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14257743/942692)

If you are indeed getting the same response, you will need to fix your request. I'm not familiar with `urllib` so I can't help you there, but if you are able to use the `requests` library instead, here's some code that works for me: (`dates` returns a ResultSet object with 20 elements)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,zh;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.5'}

session = requests.session()
response = session.get('http://www.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/advancedsearch/search_active_main_c.aspx', headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
form_data = {
    '__VIEWSTATE': soup.find('input', {'name': '__VIEWSTATE'}).get('value'),
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': soup.find('input', {'name': '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'}).get('value'),
    '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': soup.find('input', {'name': '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED'}).get('value') 
}
f = session.post('http://www.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/advancedsearch/search_active_main_c.aspx', data=form_data,
                 headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.content, 'html.parser')
dates = soup.findAll("span", {"id": lambda L: L and L.endswith('lbDateTime')})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can collect the data now.