# How can I debug this CCASS Web Scraping (aspx form) code please?

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, user-agent

The codes below are supposed to **scrape** data from an aspx website. It is however not returning anything (no error as well).

original stackoverflow post:
[Scraping .aspx page with python (HKEX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49042076/scraping-aspx-page-with-python-hkex)

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/searchsdw.aspx"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = s.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    payload = {item['name']:item.get('value','') for item in soup.select("input[name]")}
    payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'btnSearch'
    payload['txtStockCode'] = '00001'
    req = s.post(URL,data=payload,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup_obj.select("table tbody tr"): 
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("td")]
        print(data)
```

Comment: is `Detail of Market Intermediaries/Consenting Investor Participants:` table your goal?

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ and __scraping__ not scrap or scrapping. To scrap and scrapping mean throwing things away like rubbish, or fighting.

Comment: :D i noticed that @barny got tired from explaining that multiple times. good job. keep it up.

Comment: thanks a lot barny. Yes 'Details of Market Intermediaries/Consenting Investor Participants' table is the goal

Comment: I also admire @barny's persistence in educating. I do worry that their epitaph will read "s̶c̶r̶a̶p̶p̶e̶d̶ scraped in peace"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/searchsdw.aspx
```

To

```
https://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/searchsdw.aspx
```

They use security protocol

Comment: @MrTrees mark answer as correct please, if you can

Comment: of course! should be done now. if you're available for some projects, pls let me know...let's collaborate further