# Get all values of href from a class in HTML snippet using beautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a web scraping tool but I'm stuck at retrieving the css field.

Given HTML snippet, how can i get all such values of href using beautifulSoup.

Also, the class is uniquely used for this.

```
<a class="list-group-item" href="/test1/">
<a class="list-group-item" href="/test2/">
<a class="list-group-item" href="/test3/">
```

I should be able to get test1, test2 and test3.

Can someone please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python BeautifulSoup: wildcard attribute/id search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257717/python-beautifulsoup-wildcard-attribute-id-search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the elements,

```
all = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "list-group-item"}, href=True)
```

To get href

```
for ele in all:
    print(ele['href'].strip('/'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Exactly what i was looking for.