# Python: BeautifulSoup find attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to **scrape** a webite to get some percentages. So far this is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
lista=[]

site = 'https://es.investing.com/indices/indices-futures'
harware = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0'}
request = Request(site,headers=harware)
page = urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
#print(soup)

cotizacion = soup.find_all('td',{"class": "datatable_cell__3gwri datatable_cell--align-end__Wua8C datatable_cell--" + "down__2CL8n" +" datatable_cell--bold__3e0BR table-browser_col-chg-pct__9p1T3"})
for datos in cotizacion:
    indices = datos.get_text()
    lista.append(indices)
print(lista)
```

With this, I am getting a bunch of percentages in a list.
But my problem is that the class attribute only gets data when the percentage is negative because the class name is for down ("down__2CL8n"), but when it is up the class name is the same except for that part ("up__2984w"). And I wanna get both, positive and negative.
So I tryed the find with:

```
soup.find_all('td',{"class": "datatable_cell__3gwri datatable_cell--align-end__Wua8C datatable_cell--" + "down__2CL8n" or "up__2984w" +" datatable_cell--bold__3e0BR table-browser_col-chg-pct__9p1T3"})
```

But that doesn't work.
How will be the format to get a variable part of the string?

Comment: Why don't you check for both ? Because using `or` operator is not a solution for you.

Comment: I don't check for both because the order is important. The same classes are applyed in different parts, so I get different texts, but some porcentajes are positive and negative intercalate, and I need to respect the intercalate order to know which one is.

Comment: Is there a upper element that contains this two class?

Comment: I don't think so. There is a <tbody class="datatable_body__3EPFZ"> that contains all the table, but apart from that I don't see any difference.

Comment: Can you share the html. I can't say anything further without that.

Comment: Just remove the # to the print(soup) to get all the html result of the web page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired output is under the attribute `table-browser_col-chg-pct__9p1T3`, To only select the first table you can use a CSS Selector `.mb-6 td.table-browser_col-chg-pct__9p1T3`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://es.investing.com/indices/indices-futures"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

print([tag.text for tag in soup.select(".mb-6 td.table-browser_col-chg-pct__9p1T3")])
```

Output:

```
['+0,12%', '+0,73%', '+1,97%', '+0,95%', '+1,13%', '+0,03%', '-0,15%', '-0,73%', '-0,05%', '+0,22%', '-0,65%', '-0,16%', '-0,37%', '-0,21%', '+0,11%', '-0,41%', '-0,40%', '-0,15%', '-0,38%', '+0,69%', '-0,89%', '-1,13%', '+0,23%', '-0,89%', '-0,75%', '-1,51%', '-0,22%', '+0,43%', '-1,27%', '+0,92%']
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid what could be dynamic class values and instead determine which column the desired values fall under; then use `:nth-of-type` to slice out that column from the table. To get the table I would go with an attribute = value selector to get the parent element with `data-test=price-table`, then move to the child `table` element with a descendant combinator. The aim would be to try and develop something more robust over time. Of course, this introduces a header string dependency in particular.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://es.investing.com/indices/indices-futures"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0"}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
index = [i.text for i in soup.select('[data-test=price-table] table th')].index('% Var.') + 1
print([i.text for i in soup.select(f"[data-test=price-table] table td:nth-of-type({index})")])
```

---

You could also just use pandas read_html:

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html('https://es.investing.com/indices/indices-futures')[0]
table['% Var.']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this as next step(assuming the order doesn't matter):

```
cotizacion += soup.find_all('td',{"class": "datatable_cell__3gwri datatable_cell--align-end__Wua8C datatable_cell--" + "up__2984w" +" datatable_cell--bold__3e0BR table-browser_col-chg-pct__9p1T3"})
```

Edit:
As suggest by comments that the order matter, you can refer to this ans:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14257743/8651239

Comment: Yes, the order matters, otherwise I will not know which index name is each percentaje.

Comment: Is not a bad solution, is not perfect because I get not only the data I want I also get more that has the same begining of the class, but I can use it. Thank you very much.