# BeautifulSoup find_all that 'Kind of match'

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape a website and I need to get all the tags that match the first characters of my search string.

so basically there are a few divs like this:

```
<div class="" style="" id="uni-item-229925"></div>
<div class="" style="" id="uni-item-223625"></div>
<div class="" style="" id="uni-item-229325"></div>
```

and i wann geht all the divs that start with uni-item no matter what their ending number is.

If they're all the same Ii would use this:

`items = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "uni-item"})`

But for this specific Use case I'm clueless any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think John Clements answered this here beautifully (pun intended).
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14257743/16068811

So in your case:

```
items = soup.findAll("div", {"id" : re.compile('uni-item.*')})
```

or

```
items = soup.findAll("div", {"id" : lambda L: L and L.startswith('uni-item')})
```

haven't tried it but should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily using css selectors as follows:

```
items = soup.select('div[#id^ = "uni-item"]')
```

Comment: That's a wrong selector. Either suggest `soup.select('div[id^="uni-item"]')` or `soup.select('div[id*="uni-item"]')`.